# rails relation between three tables

Tags: ruby-on-rails

i think i'm getting myself in a mess, here's what I'm trying to do:

I have 3 tables, `Students, Classes and Payments`

I've currently linked the students to the classes table via `has_one :classes` and `has_many :students`

When setting up a class you can choose how many weeks the class runs for (number field that shows the weeks) e.g. 5 or 7

What i'm needing is to track the amount of payments made when the student attends the class. e.g. becky is on the sports class, she joins on week 3 of 5 and only pays 1 week.

the payment table has 3 columns so far (can add more) which is `students_id` `classes_id`, `week_paid` and `amount_paid_to_date`

I have yet to link the payments table to anything

Could you please point me in the right direction? or if this is even possible?

Thanks

Comment: I'm pretty sure that sooner or later you're going to have a problem here with the name `Classes`. `class` is a method from ruby and you'll be overwriting it in any class that has a `belongs_to` or `has_one` relation with `Classes` take that into account because Rails relies in many ways in this kind of things. Maybe naming your model with a synonym like `Lesson` will save you many problems. Also take into account that rails expects model names to be in Singular -> `Student`, `Lesson`, `Payment` in your case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see couple of problems here. If `Payment` has `student_id` and `class_id`, we say that it `belongs_to`:

```
belongs_to :student
belongs_to :class
```

You can check out [here the difference between has_one and belongs_to](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#choosing-between-belongs-to-and-has-one). Basically it depends on where you store the foreign key.

Also, Fran is right - would be better to stick with rails conventions and rename the `classes`. This will make the whole thing much easier. Let's assume you renamed it to `lessons`. Then the model for it will be called `Lesson`

Then if you want to get payments amount, you could do:

```
paid_amount = student.payments.where(lesson_id: lesson_id).sum(:amount)
```

or something like that.

Answer (score 0):

So i think i worked it out,

Student model:

```
has_many :payments
```

Classes Model:

```
has_many :students
has_many :payments
```

Payments model:

```
has_one :students
has_one :classes
```

this would probably be the most easiest way :)